# ld: framework not found CouchbaseLiteSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, couchbase-lite

I'm getting an error 
ld: framework not found CouchbaseLiteSwift
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I imported CouchbaseLiteSwift.framework  on a folder frameworks like image show [image]
i also included it on embedded binaries, and on framework search path i added : 
        $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks
        /Users/user/Documents/CouchbaseLiteTest/Frameworks
        $(PROJECT_DIR)
  /Users/user/Documents/CouchbaseLiteTest/Frameworks/CouchbaseLiteSwift.framework
        $(inherited)

But still have this error, please help